# Pass an entire object as an input property

Tags: angular

Using separate input properties for each of the properties works, but it seems unnecessary; since the object I'm passing and the object needed are of the same type.

So again, passing each property works fine (as shown below):

**Parent Component TS**

```
export class SingleCollectionPage{
    @Input() id = '' 
    collection: Collection = {id: '1', name: 'Loading...'}
    constructor(private collectionService: CollectionService) {
    }
    ngOnInit(){
        console.log('input', this.id)
        this.collectionService.getCollectionByID(this.id, true).then(c => {
            this.collection = c;     
    })
}
}
export interface Collection {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    mnemonicCount?: number,
    mnemonics?: Mnemonic[]
}
```

**Parent Component Template**

```
  <app-mnemonicCard *ngFor="let m of collection.mnemonics"
  [name]="m.name"
  [views]="m.views"
  ...
  ></app-mnemonicCard>
```

**Child Component TS**

```
export class MnemonicCard {
    @Input() name: string = '';
    @Input() views: number = 0;
    ...
}

export interface Mnemonic{
    link: string
    name: string
    stars: number
    views: number
    globalViewRank: number
    globalStarRank: number
    collectionViewRank?: number
    collectionStarRank?: number
}
```

---

So instead of that, I want to pass the entire object—Is it possible to do something like this?

**Child Component TS**

```
export class MnemonicCard {
    @Input() m: Mnemonic
}
```

**Parent Template**

```
<app-mnemonicCard *ngFor="let m of collection.mnemonics"></app-mnemonicCard>
```

Comment: Sorry didn't understand properly sure you can pass an object just in place of property pass the object are you facing any error in doing so ?

Comment: In my question, there was no console error, but the input property values didn't show up in the child component template. It became clear to me what  was wrong as soon as I saw the full syntax. ...shoulda checked devtools :facepalm:

Answer (score 0):

I see what I did incorrectly.

The input property somehow needs to become attached to the template variable in the for loop. m is not attached to anything in my question.

Looking at the expanded syntax helped me figure this out:

```
  <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="collection.mnemonics">
    <app-mnemonicCard [m]="item"></app-mnemonicCard>
  </ng-template>
```

and now the shorthand.

```
 <app-mnemonicCard [m]="mVar" *ngFor="let mVar of collection.mnemonics"></app-mnemonicCard>
```

So i bring in the m input property, assign it to the mVar template variable, and use mVar in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass Object instead of individual values using Property Binding.

Eg.

Parent Component Template.

```
<app-mnemonicCard [fullData]="collection.mnemonics"
  ...
></app-mnemonicCard>
```

Parent Component Class.

```
collection = {
  "mnemonics" : [{..}]
}
```

Child Component Class.

```
@Input() fullData: any;
```